# Flutter PlatformView: Rendering PlatformView on Realme3

Tags: flutter, android-videoview, platformview

One critical issue I'm currently facing is rendering PlatformView which is working fine on majority of Android devices be it Pixel, Samsung but it's showing black view on Realme device. Any clue if anyone have faced it before.

Flutter version: 3.16.8
Tested on device:
Samsung M04, Android 13 (working as expected)
Realme 3, Android 10 (showing black tile)

What I tried: I tried checking if the platform view I'm receiving natively is null or not and it's not null in cases when it's showing black tile which eliminates the possibility that there's a bug in our codebase.
I tried to run it on debug mode and when I add a breakpoint on rendering method and when it stops at rendering method I just simply continue it, it works as expected hence shows PlatformView (which is weird).

What I expected: It should've run when I simply ran it without adding the breakpoint.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.